# Android Management API Google Playstore iFrame changes don't reflect on managed devices

Tags: android-management-api

I've noticed that in the embedded Google Play Store iFrame for my organization, that if I add apps to a collection that are approved, those apps don't show up different in either Whitelist or Blacklist play store mode. Where are these app collections supposed to be reflected on the managed devices? If I am in Whitelist mode, I was expecting that approved applications within the Google Play store iFrame would become available to the managed devices with a policy containing Whitelist mode. Is this not how it works?

Here is a really simple policy that we were using for testing:

```
{
            "name": "enterprises/ORGANIZATION/policies/Whitelist",
            "version": "18",
            "systemUpdate": {
                "type": "POSTPONE"
            },
            "addUserDisabled": true,
            "removeUserDisabled": true,
            "locationMode": "LOCATION_USER_CHOICE",
            "networkEscapeHatchEnabled": true,
            "playStoreMode": "WHITELIST"
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the apps you want to be included in the [whitelist](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#playstoremode)
is added in your policies by using ["installType: “Available”](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#installtype)

To simplify adding these applications to your policy, your solution should use the iFrame in SELECT mode as outline in the [integration guide](https://developers.google.com/android/management/apps#add_the_iframe_to_your_console).

Your policy should look like this

```
{
 "name": "enterprises/ORGANIZATION/policies/Whitelist",
"version": "18",
"systemUpdate": {
"type": "POSTPONE"
                },
                "addUserDisabled": true,
             "removeUserDisabled": true,
                "locationMode": "LOCATION_USER_CHOICE",
                "networkEscapeHatchEnabled": true,
                "playStoreMode": "WHITELIST",
                "applications": [
                {
                "packageName": "com.linkedin.android",
                "installType": "AVAILABLE"
            },
            {
                "packageName": "com.android.chrome",
                "installType": "AVAILABLE"
             },
            {
                "packageName": "com.dropbox.android",
                "installType": "AVAILABLE"
            }
     ]
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I do have the integration in my iFrame to collect events such as 'onproductselect'. What is the intended method to move those selected applications into your policy? Are we supposed to use Patch to update the specific policy after Selecting via the iFrame? That would seem kind of clunky to the user since there wouldn't be anything updating within the full iFrame after clicking select. I must be misunderstanding the usage. Thank you

Comment: You have to retrieve the `packageName` from the `onproductselect` event and add it to your policy in order for it to be shown on the user's device as given in our example.

you can also go to this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/management/quickstart) under  `Create a policy` section for a sample policy